# How to detect with ffmpeg if the stream has video or audio or both?

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg, video, streaming

I am listening on rtsp stream. The stream *may* potentially have only audio, only video, or have both, depending on how the remote side `ffmpeg` was configured. I want to dump the stream into hls. This is the code:

```
r ffmpeg \
        -hide_banner \
        -nostats \
        -i "rtsps://....." \
        -c:v copy \
        -c:a copy \
        -hls_init_time 2 \
        -hls_time 2 \
        -hls_list_size 100 \
        -strftime 1 \
        -hls_allow_cache 1 \
        -hls_segment_type fmp4 \
        -hls_segment_filename "$MTX_PATH-%Y%m%d%H%M%S.mp4" \
        -hls_flags 'append_list+discont_start+delete_segments+omit_endlist' \
        "$MTX_PATH.m3u8"
```

However, because of `-c:v copy -v:a copy` if the stream *does not* have video, or audio, ffmpeg will fail.

How can I tell ffmpeg to copy video *if* input has video, and copy audio *if* input has audio, and copy video and audio *if* input has video and audio?

Comment: In case the only issue is `-c:v copy` and  `-c:a copy`, you may use `-c copy` for copying all the streams. There are [examples using FFprobe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278277/using-ffprobe-to-check-if-file-is-audio-or-video-only), for telling if there is a video and/or audio. It's possible to put the results in variables and use a shell script... (FFmpeg has no syntax like "`-c:a copy_if_exist`").